# When should you use IEnumerable and GetEnumerator?

Tags: c#, .net

In many of our projects I have seen a few custom collection / or container classes that hold a some sort of generic collection, e.g. a `List(of T)` class.

They usually have a GetXXX method that returns a IEnumerable of whatever type the custom collection class uses so the internal collection can be iterated around using a foreach loop.

e.g.

```
public IEnumerable<UploadState> GetStates
{
    get
    {
        return new List<UploadState>(m_states);
    }
}
```

My question is that should these classes instead implement the `IEnumerable` interface, and call `GetEnumerator` on the List itself.

Is there a preferred way, or is it up to the developer?

Comment: What is type of the m_states? Just wondering why it is wrapped by `new List<>` and returned as `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class is a custom collection class then yes, it should implement `IEnumerable<T>`. In this case a public property for the inner list would be redundant. Imagine a simple class:

```
public class People : IEnumerable<Person>
{
    List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

    public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return persons.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

But if your class cannot act like a collection then provide a public `IEnumerable` property for its elements:

```
public class Flight
{
    List<Person> passengers = new List<Person>();

    public IEnumerable<Person> Passengers
    {
        get { return passengers; }
    }
}
```

Anyway, it's always up to the developer to choose the right design.

Comment: Thanks Balazs Tihanyi, can I ask a silly question about your example, why do you implemented from IEnumerable<Person> and not IEnumberble? I am not sure.

Comment: Why would you want to? `IEnumerable<Person>` is generic and type-safe. `IEnumerable` is for .NET 1.1 or anonymous types. If you only implement the `IEnumerable` interface, you'd have to cast your list items to their type.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it that way:

```
public IEnumerable<UploadState> GetStates
{
    get
    {
        foreach (var state in m_states) { 
            yield return state; 
        }
    }
}
```

It is cleaner, your users don't get a list where they shouldn't (they could cast it to a `List<T>`after all) and you don't need to create a `List<T>`object.

**EDIT**: Misunderstood the question. I think if the class is meant to be a collection, it should implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I believe this is was not asked here so it can be a comment not an answer, but anyway makes sense from refactoring standpoint

Answer (score 1):

Consider that in your code example a **new** list created. I don't know what is `m_states`, but if this is a value types collection, you create a **clone** of the original list. In this way the returning list can be manipulated form the caller Add/Remove/Update elements. *without* affectiing original data.

If `m_states` are reference types, this still creates a **new** list which can be again manipulated by the caller Add/Remove/ **No** update elements (it's a reference!) without affecting original data.

What about `IEnumerable<T>`, its just a way to make a returning type generic, and not make strong coupling to `List<T>` type.

Comment: m_states is a reference type. Its declared as

private List<UploadState> m_states = new List<UploadState>();

I thought that method return could not be manipulated because of returning an IEnumerable<UploadState>, not a List<UploadState>?

Comment: @bobbo: sure it **can**, if you pick up an element from returning collection and change it's property, you change the property of **original** element,as this is a *reference* type.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. However, your sentence "If m_states are reference types, this still creates a new list which can be again manipulated by the caller Add/Remove/ No update elements (it's a reference!) without affecting original data." is confusing. Do you mean that the new list returned can been added to, and elements can be removed but no updates? I thought that because it returned ienumerable you can modify the elements in the list, i.e. change a property like you said but you can't add and remove items in the list. Is that correct?

Comment: I mean: if you want to execute some statistics on that list, remove elements from it add anew aggergated values (say), it will not affect in *any* way m_states list.

Answer (score 0):

You should be deriving your custom collection classes based on one of the classes in `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace. They already contain implementations of `IEnumerable<T>` and the non generic `IEnumerable` interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think if your newly implemented class just behaves the sameway as a list does, there is no need to implement it. If you need some kind of custom logic, it depends on what you want to do; you can inherit list or you can implement IEnumerable. It just depends what is to be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4074/Using-IEnumerator-and-IEnumerable-in-the-NET-Frame

I didn't read fully it yet, but I think this answers your question.